# Can base64 encoding applied to multibyte utf-8 characters?

Tags: utf-8, base64

Can base64 encoding applied to multibyte utf-8 characters ? How base64 encoded string is converted back to multibyte utf-8 string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

base64 is applied to bytes, not characters. It's up to your application to convert your strings, utf8 or not, to their bytes representation.

Comment: Does it mean that after base64 decoding we will get a byte array back and that can be further converted to utf-8 character set ?

Comment: b64 encoding takes a byte array. b64 decoding returns a byte array. That's simple.

Comment: Are you aware of any methods that take input as a byte array and return utf8 string ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure they are for a language you use.

Answer (score 1):

base64 does not care. You can use base64 encode and then decode to get back where you were.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use base64 to wrap my multi-byte text into a byte array that is easier to transmit over HTTP without loss.  I can also store my text on any database platform regardless of collation and preserve the exact text without loss.

You can then decode the byte-array back into text exactly as it were at the receiving end **BUT!** this is of course assuming your receiving end is capable of displaying the text as it was captured.  For example in my case, from one IOS device to another IOS device.

It's another issue if you wanted to display an IOS captured text out to a PHP page without loosing the emojis and multibyte characters.  That's already a matter of String encoding e.g. UTF-8, etc.