# What to do to make base64 decode functions to decode strings in local language?

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

I have this function that I grabbed long ago from somewhere:

```
function decode_base64(s)
{
    var e = {}, i, b = 0, c, x, l = 0, a, r = '', w = String.fromCharCode, L = s.length;
    var A = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        e[A.charAt(i)] = i;

    for(x = 0; x < L; x++)
    {
        c = e[s.charAt(x)];
        b = (b << 6) + c;
        l += 6;

        while(l >= 8)
            ((a = (b >>> (l -= 8)) & 0xff) || (x < (L - 2))) && (r += w(a));
    }

    return r;
};
```

In my C# app I encode strings like that:
`Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str));`

Then I generate html files where those strings are embedded.

Then JS script decodes it like that:
`decode_base64(str);`

All goes fine with English letters, but not with the local ones. They decodes into weird symbols.

`Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("HTML_SubunitsNavigator0"));
decode_base64(str); -> HTML_SubunitsNavigator0`

`Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Чекбокс")); //my native language
decode_base64(str); -> ×åêáîêñ`

I set the page encoding to `<meta http-equiv = 'Content-Type' content = 'text/html; charset = windows-1251' />` but this does not helps.

I tried to use other base64 decode functions, like that: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html but appears, that some error occurs inside those and scripts stop execution right at where I call decode method.

I tried `btoa`, but it decodes into... another "base64 lookable" sequence.

I tried to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(` with other scripts, but those stop execution anyway.

What I can do to somehow decode base64 with native language correctly?

Comment: The charset should be set to utf-8 and set everywhere to the same. This post might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587136/can-base64-encoding-applied-to-multibyte-utf-8-characters

Comment: @jeff - Eww I made so, but the only thing that changed is weird symbols. Now they are: Ð§ÐµÐºÐ±Ð¾ÐºÑ. And I use Ecoding.UTF8 to generate base64 and write html files.

Comment: `btoa()` is for encoding to Base64, for decoding use `atob()`!

Comment: @Sirko - ugh, I just messed with those. They are not useful for me anyway, since appeared in IE10, but I need to support lower IEs.

Comment: Using the script you mention i get the correct results http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/bxdd7489/. Check the js that the browser is actually seeing and make sure that it is trying to encode the characters Чекбокс. If this is hardcoded into the js then it could have been changed during transport. I had an issue with translations being messed up in moment.js and the issue was the file was being delivered as ISO-8859-1 not UTF-8.

Comment: @Quince - You got correct result because you encoded this string inside js script. In my case, base64 string is hardcoded into html page. I think there is something wrong with encodings, but can't figure what. For example, there is hardcoded "0J3QvtCy0YvQuSDRjtC90LjRgg==" which is "Новый юнит" but it decodes into something weird. Regarding other things. All my files is saved using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Ah got you, whats also weird is that  "0J3QvtCy0YvQuSDRjtC90LjRgg==" hardcoded into the script does produce Новый юнит.http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/bxdd7489/3/

Comment: @Quince - I don't know how, but everything started to decode as expected with http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html script after I modified JS saving. Looks like this script fails to decode non UTF-8 saved sequences. Sad that small function still not work, but I can live with that. You probably can make you comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the script you mention i get the correct results http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/bxdd7489/ (this is with both encoding and decoding in js)

andas in your case `"0J3QvtCy0YvQuSDRjtC90LjRgg=="` hardcoded into the script does produce Новый юнит. http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/bxdd7489/3/

and code incase fiddle ever goes down

```
/**
*
*  Base64 encode / decode
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while ( i < utftext.length ) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}


console.log( Base64.decode("0J3QvtCy0YvQuSDRjtC90LjRgg=="));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuned out, converting base64 to some local encoding (cp-1251 for example) is really funny and there-are-no-straightforward-ways-to-do thing.
I made it in two steps:

1) Convert base64 into bytes array using, for example, this [script](https://github.com/danguer/blog-examples/blob/master/js/base64-binary.js)
2) Convert bytes array into anything you want using native web API's [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) (or some [polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding))

Code snippet:

```
import encoding from 'text-encoding'; // polyfill
import { default as Base64Binary } from 'utils/base64'; // made the script importable

const win1251decoder = new encoding.TextDecoder('windows-1251');
const uint8Array = Base64Binary.decode(myXmlInBase64); //windows-1251 - originally
const xmlFile = win1251decoder.decode(uint8Array);
```

Profit! Happy coding!